# PDF of the product of a Beta random variable and a Normal random variable?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, beta-distribution

If random variable $X\,\sim\,\text{Beta}(a,b)$ and $Y\,\sim\,\text{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, is there a closed-form solution for the pdf of their product $XY$?  We assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: 1. Your title is missing some words, please edit. $\;$ 2. Note that you're not taking a product of distributions, but the distribution of a product of random variables, so the edit to the title is not just a matter of adding "product of" in between 'of' and 'beta'. $\:$ 3. It depends on their joint distribution, not just their margins. $\:$ 4. If they were independent, (which you haven't stated), you can write a 'simple' integral down for the distribution of the product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables

Comment: ... but it may well not have a closed form result.

Comment: The addition of the assumption of independence by the OP resolves any uncertainty as to what the question is asking. Plainly not an easy question to solve, and will be interesting to see what the community can come up with, or if there are any published papers dealing with same.

Comment: [Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099424) is a published paper. This does not look like self-study to me!  A link for a very special case:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008559/pdf-of-product-of-standard-normal-and-uniform